# How to make tabs with text

Tags: javascript, foreach

I recently started to study JS and wanted to do a clickable tab showing different text with forEach method, but unfortunately i'm struggling!

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.text');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

    //make buttons active
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
      button.classList.remove('active')
    })
    event.target.classList.add('active')

    //show text
    texts.forEach(text => {
      text.classList.remove('text');
    })
  });

})
```

```html
<button class="button">Tab1</button>
<button class="button">Tab2</button>
<button class="button">Tab3</button>

<div class="text-tabs">
  <div class="text">
    <h4>Text from tab1</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <h4>Text from tab2</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <h4>Text from tab3</h4>
  </div>
```

The CSS already has the display: none and then block

Comment: Could you add in the CSS you are using to the snippet as well?

Comment: I was trying to but I keep getting the formatting error when i paste the css..

Answer (score 1):

a way to do it is to add a data attribute to your different tab (for sample an id or an index) `<button class="button" data-tab="1">Tab1</button>`

and recover this value when you click on element
`event.target.dataset.tab`

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.text');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

    //make buttons active
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
      button.classList.remove('active')
    })
    event.target.classList.add('active')
    texts.forEach(text => text.classList.add('hidden'));
    const tabToShow = document.querySelector(`.text:nth-child(${event.target.dataset.tab})`);
    if (tabToShow) {
      tabToShow.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
    
  });

})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" data-tab="1">Tab1</button>
<button class="button" data-tab="2">Tab2</button>
<button class="button" data-tab="3">Tab3</button>

<div class="text-tabs">
  <div class="text hidden">
    <h4>Text from tab1</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="text hidden">
    <h4>Text from tab2</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="text hidden">
    <h4>Text from tab3</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```